# Can't input any special characters in OS X terminal when using ZSH

Tags: macos, character-encoding, osx-yosemite, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I can't input any special characters (e.g., äöå) in OS X terminal when I'm using ZSH shell (with oh-my-zsh plugin). If a try to input one of those characters I only get the default mac error sound alert and no visible characters. However, if I switch to bash, everything works correctly.

The terminal is set to utf-8 and my .zshrc contains:

```
export LANG=fi_FI.UTF-8
export LANG="fi_FI.UTF-8"
export LC_COLLATE="fi_FI.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="fi_FI.UTF-8"
```

I'm using OS X Yosemite and my language is set to finnish.

```
~  locale
LANG="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: use iTerm, Terminal is known to have such problems.

Answer (score 0):

Add this shell initialization within `~/.zprofile`:

```
# Correctly display UTF-8 with combining characters.
# This part is included in /etc/zshrc in some recent versions of MacOS
if [ "$TERM_PROGRAM" = "Apple_Terminal" ]; then
        setopt combiningchars
fi
# Don't strip 8th bit
stty -istrip
LANG=fi_FI.UTF-8
export LANG
```

You don't have to include anything inside `~/.zshrc` since this doesn't have to be repeated at each shell level.